# OpenCV HLS Sharpening

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to make the Sharpening of an Image in HLS format.
I've done the Blurring correctly, but the Sharpening doesn't work.

I know the Sharpening is:

```
1) Blur the Image: Image -> Blurred. 2) Make Unsharp Mask: Unsharp_Mask = Image - Blurred. 3) Sharpen the Image: Sharpened = Image + Unsharp_Mask
```

Also I know in HLS you don't have to do this in every channel, but just in the "L" one.
I did it, but it doesn't work.

This is my code (i can't use the "code" button cause it gives me error - says that there are parts of the code that are not properly formatted as code):

```
// UNSHARP MASK HLS Mat* UnsharpHLS = new Mat(PaddedHLS->rows, PaddedHLS->cols, PaddedHLS->type()); Mat* SharpHLS = new Mat(PaddedHLS->rows, PaddedHLS->cols, PaddedHLS->type());

for (int i = 0; i < ImageHLS.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ImageHLS.cols; j++)
    {
        UnsharpHLS->at<Vec3b>(i+1, j+1)[1] = ImageHLS.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] - PaddedHLS->at<Vec3b>(i + 1, j + 1)[1];
        SharpHLS->at<Vec3b>(i+1, j+1)[1] = ImageHLS.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] + (UnsharpHLS->at<Vec3b>(i + 1, j + 1)[1]);
    } }

cvtColor(*SharpHLS, Sharpened, COLOR_HLS2BGR);
```

Let's assume the previous part of the code works (I don't get any error and I've already tryed it), the only problem is in the mentioned code.

This is the whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // CARICAMENTO IMMAGINE
    Mat Original = imread("Lena.png", IMREAD_COLOR);

    // VERIFICA SE L'IMMAGINE E' STATA LETTA CORRETTAMENTE, IN CASO CONTRARIO RITORNA -1
    if (Original.empty())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    

    // CONVERSIONE COLORI
    Mat ImageHLS;
    Mat ImageRGB;
    Mat Blurred;
    Mat Sharpened;

    cvtColor(Original, ImageRGB, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    cvtColor(Original, ImageHLS, COLOR_BGR2HLS);



    // CREAZIONE IMMAGINE HLS PADDED
    int FilterSize = 3;
    int Padding = FilterSize - 1;
    Mat* PaddedHLS = new Mat(ImageHLS.rows + Padding, ImageHLS.cols + Padding, ImageHLS.type());
    copyMakeBorder(ImageHLS, *PaddedHLS, Padding / 2, Padding / 2, Padding / 2, Padding / 2, BORDER_DEFAULT);

    // BLURRING SU IMMAGINE HLS PADDED
    Mat* Filter = new Mat(FilterSize, FilterSize, ImageHLS.type());

    for (int i = 1; i < PaddedHLS->rows - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < PaddedHLS->cols - 1; j++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < FilterSize; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < FilterSize; y++)
                {
                    Filter->at<Vec3b>(x, y)[1] = PaddedHLS->at<Vec3b>(i - 1 + x, j - 1 + y)[1];
                }
            }

            PaddedHLS->at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = mean(*Filter).val[1];
        }
    }

    cvtColor(*PaddedHLS, Blurred, COLOR_HLS2BGR);



    // UNSHARP MASK HLS
    Mat* UnsharpHLS = new Mat(PaddedHLS->rows, PaddedHLS->cols, PaddedHLS->type());
    Mat* SharpHLS = new Mat(PaddedHLS->rows, PaddedHLS->cols, PaddedHLS->type());

    for (int i = 0; i < ImageHLS.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ImageHLS.cols; j++)
        {
            UnsharpHLS->at<Vec3b>(i+1, j+1)[1] = ImageHLS.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] - PaddedHLS->at<Vec3b>(i + 1, j + 1)[1];
            SharpHLS->at<Vec3b>(i+1, j+1)[1] = ImageHLS.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] + (UnsharpHLS->at<Vec3b>(i + 1, j + 1)[1]);
        }
    }

    cvtColor(*SharpHLS, Sharpened, COLOR_HLS2BGR);



    // VISUALIZZAZIONE IMMAGINI
    imshow("Originale", Original);
    imshow("Image RGB", ImageRGB);
    imshow("Image HLS", ImageHLS);
    imshow("Blurred HLS", *PaddedHLS);
    imshow("Blurred BGR", Blurred);
    imshow("Unsharp HLS", *UnsharpHLS);
    imshow("Sharpened HLS", *SharpHLS);
    imshow("Sharpened BGR", Sharpened);

    //CHIUDI TUTTO
    waitKey(0);
    destroyAllWindows();
}
```

Comment: do you think "doesn't work" is sufficient?

Comment: well, if there's something wrong in the code I think one would notice.

btw, the problem is that the sharpened image is "yellowish". Both in the HLS and BGR versions it is not a sharpened version of the original image, but a yellowish version of it.